# What can I do if msvcr80.dll is missing?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office-2007

I have MS-Office 07 setup in my system. But it seems like if its one DLL got corrupted called `msvcr80.dll`.
When I try to install office now, it says Setup cannot find `Office.en-us\msvcr80.dll`. Browse to a valid installation source, and then click Ok.

I got this error previously as well. But I downloaded this dll from internet and replaced it with mine. It worked perfectly, but I just lost that link of the website from where I got the dll. Many sites has this dll but not working for me. I dnt have CD of MS-Office right now. I have the setup in my system.

Comment: https://encrypted.google.com/#hl=en&sugexp=ppwl&cp=41&gs_id=2&xhr=t&q=office+2007+setup+cannot+find+msvcr80.dll&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&site=&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=office+2007+setup+cannot+find+msvcr80.dll&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=69943cc77b5c0351&biw=1245&bih=863

Answer (score 9):

Here is the [link](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=3387) for the Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable Package (x86)

Answer (score 4):

You should reinstall Microsoft redistributable packages. If you want to have less problems in the future, you should install all of them
For x86-64 you should install x64 and x86 packages.

- [VS Redist 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784)
- [VS Redist 2012 Update 4](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679)

  **x86**
- [VS Redist 2010 SP1 x86](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328)
- [VS Redist 2010 x86](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555)
- [VS Redist 2008 SP1 x86](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582)
- [VS Redist 2008 x86](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29)
- [VS Redist 2008 Feature Pack x86](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10015) (XP, 2003, Vista)
- [VS Redist 2005 SP1 x86](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5638)
- [VS Redist 2005 x86](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3387) (XP, 2003)

  **x64**
- [VS Redist 2010 SP1 x64](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13523)
- [VS Redist 2010 x64](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632)
- [VS Redist 2008 SP1 x64](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2092)
- [VS Redist 2008 x64](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15336)
- [VS Redist 2008 Feature Pack x64](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16771) (XP, 2003, Vista)
- [VS Redist 2005 SP1 x64](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18471)
- [VS Redist 2005 x64](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21254) (XP, 2003)

**ia64**

- [VS Redist 2010 SP1 ia64](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21051)
- [VS Redist 2010 ia64](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2054)
- [VS Redist 2008 SP1 ia64](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19823)
- [VS Redist 2008 ia64](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4887)
- [VS Redist 2008 Feature Pack ia64](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3218) (only XP, 2003, Vista)
- [VS Redist 2005 SP1 ia64](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13360)
- [VS Redist 2005 ia64](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16326) (XP, 2003)

Comment: I reinstalled this and restarted my pc. But it still ask for the same file while installing MS-Office 07. Any reason?

Comment: I've improved my answer with links to all VC Redist packages. For x64 OS you really need x64 **and** x86 packages.

Comment: After installation of VC Redists, copy correct dll to your Setup